# Can We Hide Scrollbar in ScrollView Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

As stated at the title

Is it possible to hide the scrollbar in `ScrollView` Xamarin.Forms without having to create a custom renderer for each platform?

I can't seem to find any answers, suggestions, or examples that are not using custom renderer.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28741/how-to-hide-the-scrollbar see this

Comment: No, this cannot be done without the use of a `CustomRenderer`

Comment: @DoughnutZombie I already read that article and it used `CustomRenderer`

@GeraldVersluis I see, could you please give me a pointer to understand how to use `CustomRenderer`?

Comment: Sure it is not that hard. Maybe you can start by reading my blog post about this; https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/bibbidi-bobbidi-boo-using-custom-renderers-to-enchant-your-ui/ I will create an anwser post meanwhile

Answer (score 13):

*edit Mar 7, 2018:* for Googleability: a [PR was merged](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/1910) which adds this ability to the default Xamarin.Forms toolkit. It should be released in the NuGets soon.

**Original answer:**

As stated in the comments you are not able to achieve this without the use of a `CustomRenderer`.

Create a class `ScrollViewExRenderer` in your iOS and Droid project and put this in it, the code taken from the link in the comments as well;

```
public class ScrollViewExRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement == null || this.Element == null)
            return;

        if (e.OldElement != null)
            e.OldElement.PropertyChanged -= OnElementPropertyChanged;

        e.NewElement.PropertyChanged += OnElementPropertyChanged;

    }

    protected void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ChildCount > 0)
        {
            GetChildAt(0).HorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false;
            GetChildAt(0).VerticalScrollBarEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Above the namespace declaration put this line;

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ScrollView), typeof(ScrollViewExRenderer))]
```

Now your `ScrollView`s should not show any scrollbars

Comment: Thanks man and sorry for replying after some time, but may I ask you how to hide the scrollbar for Windows Phone too?

Comment: @gerald-versluis I know this is an old question/answer, but it looks like there's an error in `OnElementChanged`. The method will never execute the line `e.OldElement.PropertyChanged -= OnElementPropertyChanged;` because it would require `e.OldElement != null`, but if that's true, the method will exit out from the `if` statement above it. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Hi Dave! That might be the case. I’d have to check. But I can do even better; I know for a fact that this will be part of Xamarin.Forms by default in the very near future! I will take another pass at this answer and update as needed. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @DaveWood updated the answer with both the reference to the PR that got merged and fixed the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Hey this seems a bit late to post an answer but since you haven't selected an answer i will post the procedure for android and windows projects. The answer given by gerald might have been true at some point but i couldn't get it to work maybe because xamarin has changed a lot.

Create a new class in .DROID and .UWP projects and add the following code

For .UWP

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ScrollView), typeof(App3.UWP.Scrollbardisabledrenderer))]

namespace App3.UWP
{
    public class Scrollbardisabledrenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {


            Control.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
            Control.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;

        }


    }

}
```

For .DROID

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;



[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ScrollView), typeof(App3.Droid.Scrollbardisabledrenderer))]

namespace App3.Droid
{
    public class Scrollbardisabledrenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || this.Element == null)
                return;

            if (e.OldElement != null)
                e.OldElement.PropertyChanged -= OnElementPropertyChanged;

            e.NewElement.PropertyChanged += OnElementPropertyChanged;



        }

        protected void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {


                this.HorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false;
                this.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = false;



        }
    }
}
```

I'm sorry about .IOS I can't confirm whether my code is working or not because I dont have a mac.

Comment: Inside OnElementPropertyChanged the right code is:

if (ChildCount > 0)
        {
            GetChildAt(0).HorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false;
            GetChildAt(0).VerticalScrollBarEnabled = false;
        }

Answer (score 2):

@Akaya93 @Zany you can hide scrollbar for iOS using the next code:

```
this.ShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
this.ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have vertical ScrollView, you can put `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"` in your xaml:

`<ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">`

If you have horizontal ScrollView, you can put `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility ="Never"` in your xaml:

`<ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility ="Never">`

Answer (score 0):

To hide ScrollBar in ***XamarinForms*** on my Android solution I used this:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/73353/how-to-hide-scroll-bar-in-scrollview

But for IOS you have to change a code a bit:

```
public class ScrollBarDisabledRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer    
{   
     protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
     {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            return;

        if (e.OldElement != null)
            e.OldElement.PropertyChanged -= OnElementPropertyChanged;
        e.NewElement.PropertyChanged += OnElementPropertyChanged;
      }

    private void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
        ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
    }
}
```

Above the namespace declaration:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyScrollView), typeof(ScrollBarDisabledRenderer))]
```

So, name of properties is different for IOS:

`ShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
 ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;`

Answer (score -1):

this code works on Android and for IOS replace :

```
this.HorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false;
this.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = false;
```

by

```
ShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
ShowsVerticalScrollIndicator = false;
```

Comment: You are not answering the question. The OP is specifically asking for a way to do this with one code set, not two different ones per platform.